# How to save phone number with braces and minuses if I use XSS filter?

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding, xss

I use third party XSS filter to secure my application from xss attacks(`com.cj.xss.XSSFilter`)

But I faced following issue:

I am saving phone number in format like this:

```
+7 (911) 111-11-11
```

but on server I see that phone looks like this:

```
+7 &#40;911&#41; 111-11-11
```

As I understand it is encoding result.

I want to allow user to use phone number with braces, minuses and spaces.
Is it possible to achieve without security hole ?

Comment: 0_o How are just parentheses an XSS attack vector to begin with?

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara please rephrase your message. My english does not good. I cannot understand your message

Comment: I was just asking out loud why those parentheses would be encoded in the first place. I can't think of any XSS attacks that can be done with just those characters. I'm not familiar with your XSS filter, but perhaps they are encoded somewhere else.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara I tried to disable filter and at this case - braces doesn't replace